# Car fueling problem with a greedy algorithmic solution is giving wrong output

Tags: c++, greedy

I am solving a problem called Car Fueling on coursera and I followed the pseudocode that had been given. The problem states:

> You are going to travel to another city that is located `d` miles away from your home city. Your car can travel at most `m` miles on a full tank and you start with a full tank.
> Along your way, there are gas stations at distances stop 1, stop 2, . . . , stop `n` from your home city. What is the minimum number of refills needed?
>
> Input Format.
> The first line contains an integer `d`.
> The second line contains an integer `m`.
> The third line specifies an integer `n`.
> Finally, the last line contains integers stop 1, stop 2, . . . , stop `n`.
>
> Output Format.
> Assuming that the distance between the cities is `d` miles, a car can travel at most `m` miles  on a full tank, and there are gas stations at distances stop 1, stop 2, . . . , stop `n` along the way, output the minimum number of refills needed. Assume that the car starts with a full tank. If it is not possible to reach the destination, output `−1`.

Here is the function to solve the problem:

```cpp
int compute_min_refills(int dist, int tank, vector<int> & stops) {
    int curref=0;//current position of the car
    int numref=0;//number of refills
    int lastref=0;//last position of the car
    int n=stops.size();//the amount of stops to refill at
    while(curref<=n){
        if(curref>=n){return -1;}
        lastref=curref;
        while((curref<=n) && (stops[curref+1]-stops[lastref]<=tank)){curref=curref+1;}

        if(curref==lastref){return -1;}

        if(curref<=n){numref=numref+1;}
    }       
    return numref;
}
```

When I submit, it fails on the first test case, but I don't know what could be causing it to give error.

The test case:

```
Input:
500
200
4
100 200 300 400

Your output:
1

Correct output:
2
```

Comment: You have the input and the expected output. That should make it very easy to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, and to see when and where things start to go wrong. To make debugging easier I suggest you split up complex expressions into smaller and simpler expressions, so you can easily see their results. The same with multiple statements on single lines, using multiple lines makes it easier to see what's really happening.

Comment: Something you need to watch out for (and is the likely reason for your problem): Make sure you don't go out of bounds of the `stops` vector (which you might do with the code you show).